# Dúvida em alterar dados em PHP MVC

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mvc, crud, atualização

Preciso atualizar os dados de um cliente no meu projeto MVC. É um formulário que deve atualizar duas tabelas no banco: "usuario" e "logradouro", porém só "usuario" está sendo atualizado, o que pode ser?

Não retorna nenhum erro, só não está sendo feita a atualização do logradouro no banco.

**Este é o formulário que pega os novos dados**

```
<form action="<?= url("admin/usuario/salvar") . "/" . $data[0]['cod_usu']?>" method="post">
        <div style="border-radius: 5px;
                    border-style: solid;
                    border-color: cyan;
                    border-widht: 1px;
                    padding: 10px;
                    margin-top: 10px;
                    margin-bottom:10px;";>

<?php if($data[0]['cod_status_usu'] == 'A'): ?>
        <label class="container">Ativo
            <input type="radio" checked name="cod_status_usu" value="A">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>

        <label class="container">Inativo
            <input type="radio" name="cod_status_usu" value="I">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>

    <?php else:?>
            <label class="container">Ativo
            <input type="radio" name="cod_status_usu" value="A">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>

        <label class="container">Inativo
            <input type="radio" checked name="cod_status_usu" value="I">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label>
        
     <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAdress">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<?=$data[0]['email_usu']?>" placeholder="" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAdress">Nome de Usuario</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeUsuario" name="nomeUsuario" value="<?=$data[0]['nome_usu']?>" placeholder="" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="inputZip">CEP</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control cep-mask" name="cep" maxlength="9" OnKeyPress="formatar('#####-###', this)" value="<?=$data[0]['cep_logra'] ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="inputCity">Numero</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numero" name="numero" value="<?=$data[0]['num_logra'] ?>" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAdress">Complemento</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="complemento" name="complemento" value="<?=$data[0]['compl_logra'] ?>" placeholder="" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Esté é o código no AdminController (parcial)**

```
public function user($data): void {
        try {

            $usuario = new Usuario();
            $usuario->setCod_usu($data['cod_usu']);
            $usuarioDao = new UsuarioDao();

            $data = $usuarioDao->readUserId($usuario);
            $toView = new ToView(URL_VIEW_ADMIN);
            $toView->viewStandard('usuario', $data);

        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            //throw $th;
        }
    }

    public function saveUser($data): void{
        try {
          $data = filter_var_array($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);


          $usuario = new Usuario();
          $usuario->setCod_usu($data['cod_usu']);
          $usuario->setCod_status_usu($data['cod_status_usu']);
  
          $usuarioDao = new UsuarioDao();
          $usuarioDao->updateUserId($usuario);
          $data = $usuarioDao->readUserId($usuario);
          $toView = new ToView(URL_VIEW_ADMIN);
          $toView->viewStandard('usuario',$data);
          
        } catch (\Exception $exception){
  
        }
  }

  public function saveUserLogra($data): void{
    try {
      $data = filter_var_array($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);

      $lo = new Logradouro();
      $lo->setCod_logra($data['cod_logra']);
      $lo->setCep_logra($data['cep_logra']);
      $lo->setNum_logra($data['num_logra']);
      $lo->setCompl_logra($data['compl_logra']);

      $loDao = new LogradouroDao();
      $loDao->updateLograId($lo);

      
    } catch (\Exception $exception){

    }
}
```

**Este é o UsuarioDao (parcial)**

```
    public function read() {
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT cod_tipo_usu,cod_usu, nome_usu,  cep_logra, email_usu, tel_usu, cod_status_usu from usuario
            inner join logradouro on usuario.cod_logra = logradouro.cod_logra";
            $stmt = Conexao::getConn()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                $result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $result;
            }else{
                return [];
            }      
          } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
            throw $exception;
    }

    }

    public function readUserId(Usuario $user) {
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario inner join logradouro on usuario.cod_logra = logradouro.cod_logra WHERE cod_usu = ?";
            $stmt = Conexao::getConn()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $user->getCod_usu());
            $stmt->execute();
            
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                $result = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $result;
            }else{
                return [];
            }      
          } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
            throw $exception;
    }

    }

    

    public function updateUserId(Usuario $user) {
        try {
            $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET cod_status_usu = ?
                                          WHERE cod_usu = ?"; 
            $stmt = Conexao::getConn()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $user->getCod_status_usu());
            $stmt->bindValue(2, $user->getCod_usu());
            
            return $stmt->execute();
              
          } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
            throw $exception;
    }

    }
```

**Este é o LogradouroDao (parcial)**

```
 public function updateLograId(Logradouro $lo) {
        try {
            $sql = "UPDATE logradouro SET cep_logra = ?,
                                          num_logra = ?,
                                          compl_logra = ?
                                        WHERE cod_logra = ?";
            $stmt = Conexao::getConn()->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $lo->getCep_logra());
            $stmt->bindValue(2, $lo->getNum_logra());
            $stmt->bindValue(3, $lo->getCompl_logra());
            $stmt->bindValue(4, $lo->getCod_logra());

            return $stmt->execute();
             
          } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
            throw $exception;
    }

    }
```

[image: UsuarioDao]
[image: LogradouroDao]
[image: AdminControlle (1)]
[image: AdminControlle (2)]

Comment: Supondo que esta url `admin/usuario/salvar` é resolvida para executar a ação `public function saveUser($data)`, o logradouro nunca será realmente atualizado, pois dentro desta função você somente tem código executando alterações no Usuário.

Comment: Olá, desculpe a demora. Estou usando essas duas linhas no meu index.php, teria algo errado?                                                                                        $router->post("/usuario/salvar/{cod_logra}","AdminController:saveUserLogra"); 
$router->post("/usuario/salvar/{cod_usu}","AdminController:saveUser");

Comment: A questão não me parece estar no rota e sim dentro da ação (função do controlador que executa o código)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que colocou no comentário somente uma das ações é executada, você está esperando que ambas as rotas sejam executadas mas - pensando nos padrões de implementação de roteamento, somente uma é pois ao passar a configuração de segmento com variável diferente mas mesma base de url para rota, o parser do roteamento provavelmente está identificando apenas uma delas:

```
$router->post("/usuario/salvar/{cod_logra}","AdminController:saveUserLogra"); 
$router->post("/usuario/salvar/{cod_usu}","AdminController:saveUser");
```

O parser enxerga: `/usuario/salvar/{UMAVARIAVEL}`

Uma possível solução, pensando que sua tela de alteração tem tanto os campos para alterar usuário quanto para alterar logradouro, deixe apenas a rota de salvar usuário

Em seu *index.php*

```
$router->post("/usuario/salvar/{cod_usu}","AdminController:saveUser");
```

E no *AdminController_ unifique as funções saveUser e SaveLogra:

```
public function saveUser($data): void{
         $data = filter_var_array($data, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED);

        // SALVANDO USUÁRIO
        try {
          $usuario = new Usuario();
          $usuario->setCod_usu($data['cod_usu']);
          $usuario->setCod_status_usu($data['cod_status_usu']);
  
          $usuarioDao = new UsuarioDao();
          $usuarioDao->updateUserId($usuario);
          
        } catch (\Exception $exception){
  
        }

    // SALVANDO LOGRA
    try {
      $lo = new Logradouro();
      $lo->setCod_logra($data['cod_logra']);
      $lo->setCep_logra($data['cep_logra']);
      $lo->setNum_logra($data['num_logra']);
      $lo->setCompl_logra($data['compl_logra']);

      $loDao = new LogradouroDao();
      $loDao->updateLograId($lo);

      
    } catch (\Exception $exception){

    }

     $data = $usuarioDao->readUserId($usuario);
     $toView = new ToView(URL_VIEW_ADMIN);
     $toView->viewStandard('usuario',$data);

}
```

Comment: Segui a sua dica e acontece o seguinte erro: "Notice: Undefined index: cod_usu in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto-kdovo\src\App\AdminController.php on line 86" .

Comment: Parte do código em que o erro aponta: `public function user($data): void {
        try {

            $usuario = new Usuario();`
            **(linha 86)** `$usuario->setCod_usu($data['cod_usu']);`
            `$usuarioDao = new UsuarioDao();

            $data = $usuarioDao->readUserId($usuario);
            $toView = new ToView(URL_VIEW_ADMIN);
            $toView->viewStandard('usuario', $data);

        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            //throw $th;
        }
    }`

Comment: Ao retirar a linha: `$router->get("/usuario/{cod_logra}","AdminController:user");`, o código não apresenta erro até então, mas ao tentar salvar os dados e fazer o update nas duas tabelas, o seguinte erro aparece: " Notice: Undefined index: cod_logra in C:\xampp\htdocs\projeto-kdovo\src\App\AdminController.php on line 118", e apenas a tabela usuário é alterada.

Comment: Você precisa validar os códigos vindos da interface e a origem destas variáveis, veja, eu apontei uma possível solução para a lógica de sua pergunta inicial. Para lhe ajudar detalhadamente com o código depurando todas as alterações, o ideal seria entrar em contato no privado.